# Usernotification when the screen is locked

Tags: ios, swift, notifications

I want set notifications to fire, even if the screen is locked. 
The code:

```
let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: String(index), content: content, trigger: trigger)
let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
center.add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)
```

It works like a charm,while the app is in the background. But when the screen is locked there is no vibration and no sound. It seems like the notification is not being delivered. How can I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have user's permission to show notification on lock screen:

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound , .badge]) {(accepted, error) in
     if !accepted {
            // notification access denied
     }
}
```

Comment: I already asked for alert and sound. I added .badge and now it works, Thank you